# How to disable scroll when dropdown menu is active?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I disable screen scroll if `.nav-icon-underlay.active` is on,  which also means that my navigation menu is showing in a mobile width?

My problem is that my nav menu disappears when I scroll with the following script:

```
//HIDE OR SHOW NAVBAR WHEN SCROLLING
$(window).on( 'DOMMouseScroll mousewheel', function ( event ) {
  //identifying wheelData: wheelDeltaX & wheelDeltaY
  if ( event.originalEvent.detail > 0 || event.originalEvent.wheelDelta < 0 ){
    //hides navbar when scrolling down
    $('.nav-container').slideUp();
  }
  else {
    //adds navbar when scrolling up
    $('.nav-container').slideDown();
  }
});

/*CSS*/
.nav-container.active {
height: 100%;
transition: .7s;
top: 0;
display: block;
}/* show drop-down menu */
/*HIGHLIGHT*/

.nav-container.scroll {
 display: block;
 }
```

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well the easiest way would be to use a conditional to check whether the `nav-icon-underlay` has the class `active`, which can be done with jQuery's **[`hasClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/)** method.

If the class is not present, your page must not be showing at a mobile width. As such, simply wrap your scrolling logic inside the following:

```
if (!$('.nav-icon-underlay'.hasClass('active') { }
```

Which combined with your existing code looks like:

```
$(window).on( 'DOMMouseScroll mousewheel', function ( event ) {
  if (!$('.nav-icon-underlay'.hasClass('active') {
    //identifying wheelData: wheelDeltaX & wheelDeltaY
    if ( event.originalEvent.detail > 0 || event.originalEvent.wheelDelta < 0 ){
      //hides navbar when scrolling down
      $('.nav-container').slideUp();
    }
    else {
      //adds navbar when scrolling up
      $('.nav-container').slideDown();
    }
  }
});
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thanks for your comment but it doesn't seem to work. For now, I ended up using .addClass() after $('.nav-container') to activate a shrunken version of my nav-bar when scrolling down. Prior to this, I was able to hide my navbar when scrolling down on a wider screen width, but my problem is it's also triggering the drop-down menu to close on a mobile width if I accidentally scroll.  I was thinking of disabling the mouse scroll value on a mobile width when the drop-down menu is open? Any other suggestions would be appreciated. Sorry, I'm fairly new to JQuery and JS lol.